# Directly Attach Files from Box.net in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, cloud-storage, box.com

Is there a way to directly attach a bunch of files (JPEG images, if the type matters) from my Box.net account to an e-mail that I'm composing in Thunderbird?

Note that I *don't* want to hotlink to these files, I just want to send them as *attachments* in an e-mail.

For clarification, currently I accomplish this task in the following way:

1. Download files (JPEG Images) from Box.net account to local machine.
2. Fire-up e-mail Client (Thunderbird) and compose new message.
3. Attach files from Step-1 to the new message and send it to intended recipients.

What I'm looking for is a tool/method/option that'll let me skip Step-1 entirely.

Comment: Why not use the box.net client to keep your files synced locally?

Comment: @Paul: The problem that I'm facing is that I want to e-mail them to a friend, not use/view them on the local PC. So using the Box client is not an option